# Can I fixing control's position in rdlc report C#?

Tags: c#, report, rdlc, reportviewer

if control's height over one paper size, control move next page...

I want to fix them where I positioning.

if they height over current page, cut over parts and showing next page cutted parts.

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FngDe.png)

does it can?

Answer (score 0):

If you're dynamically building the report from code you can certainly do that.
For a report being built dynamically, you'll need to track the approximate sizes of the page as well as the individual control heights.
If the control would take up more space than the available space on the page, you can enter a page break.

You have complete control on the output if you use GDI+ to generate the report view.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, It doesn't dynamically build. and I tried checking options but it wasn't work like my hopes too